# need help on sending email from wampserver or live server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing one application which include the email sending functionality
(which is like i have one table in which all email details are there. I need a script which will work continueously on server. if it found any record in queuetable it will sending email from server). Note.  1) if i am closing application then the script wont stop. it must have to execute for sending email if it found emials in que table.

can any one tell me how to do that. because if i close my application or close the browser then it will stop working. I dont want to do that . if i close  my applicaiton or browser then it must continue to work of sending email.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all right, 
First of all for running a script even if you close your browser you need a cron job for apache and a scheduled task for IIS.
here is a tutorial for cron job

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/

What you need to do:
1) write a script which checks database table for data and if records found it sends email. 
2) add this script to cron job 
3) You are done.